# What type of screws and rawl plugs should I use?

Tags: walls, screws

I have a a framed canvas picture that I need to hang on a the wall. It is about 3 foot in height and 2 foot wide.

The wall is made of solid brick but has been boarded over with plasterboard and then plastered and painted.

What type of plugs should I use for this? Also what length screws? I was thinking they would have to be fairly long, maybe 50-60mm, to fix in to the brick?

I am assuming that this will require at least 2 screws to be fixed to the wall securely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 feet high, 2 feet wide. Can't weigh more than 30-40 pounds, and that's on the high side. I personally think you can get away with one good anchor. Once you go to 2, you want to have them dead level with each other, or you'll have to battle the alignment monster.

Get a 1/4 lag bolt shield and a 1 3/4" long lag bolt, get the proper sized masonry drill bit (it will be specified on the packaging) and make sure that you account for the depth of the plaster when you drill. Probably should drill a total of 1 5/8ths deep from the surface of the wall. Then tap the shield in as far as you can get it and tighten the lag down. Just leave a small gap between the plaster and the bolt head when you tighten it. Then hang the string right in that gap. That should be good up to about a hundred pounds WITH safety factor applied. Failure point is about 200 I believe, over 4x what I'm assuming the weight is.

I just realized you're metric. I don't know enough about metric lag bolts and thread sizes to convert what I've said, but perhaps you can get the gist of it.

Comment: I agree only one anchor is needed. A lag and shield would be more than adequate. It may be worth checking if hardened masonry screw anchors are available where you are. They screw directly into a much smaller hole with no insert required. The 1/4" size are rated for 250 pounds into the face shell of hollow CMU, so are plenty strong in a solid brick wall. An embedment of 3cm into brick would be adequate.